# Percentage of waiting-list students offered a PhD position

Tags: application

As a result of comments on my [earlier question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1644/what-percentage-of-admitted-phd-students-comes-from-waiting-lists#comment2562_1644), I am posting another question.

Is there a rule of thumb for what percentage of waiting-list students is eventually placed, or invited, for a PhD position.

Comment: This is far too broad to answer. It depends on where you are applying? Which country, for starters? Which university?

Comment: I agree that it's very broad, that's why I am asking for a rule of thumb, or just post ad-hoc answers. I am sure people are interested in this.

Comment: Rule of thumb is that the number placed equals the number of positions that come available.

Comment: I don't see the point in making a new question, it is very likely if one had the statistics to provide the answer to one of these questions they would have the statistics for the other. The numerator in each percent is the same, it is just the denominator that is different. I'm skeptical any such statistics exist on a widespread basis anyway.

Comment: The numerator in the first case is the number of students that accept the position, in this case it is the number of students that are offered the position. The difference is those that are offered a position, but do not accept. I know it would be hard to come up with percentages, that is why I said rule of thumb.

Comment: I think it depends a little bit on the status of the department/university. High status universities are more likely to be the first choice, whereas lower status universities are likely to be a second, third, or fourth choice, which means that they are likely to get more rejections in their initial round of offers, and hence make greater use of a reserve list.

Comment: @DaveClarke That is tautological. I asked for a percentage of total on the waiting list. Also it should include those that are accepted in e.g. the second round but refuse.

Comment: Seconding @JeromyAnglim's comment.  I think the answer is essentially zero for the top 10 (or 20) American computer science departments.  (My department doesn't have a waiting list, for instance.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there really isn't a rule of thumb for this.

For graduate departments that admit on a fixed cycle, they generally have a certain number of places open each year. They admit from their applicant pool a number of applicants that, when all decisions are made, are designed to give them their target number of enrollees. If, for some reason, the number of students who accept is significantly smaller than the target, and there were good students who were wait-listed, they *may* be offered admission, although this is by no means guaranteed.

For graduate departments that do rolling admissions this is obviously not an issue, as they don't need a wait list.